# Parsing a web response that is a binary encoded octet stream

Tags: c#, encoding, webrequest

I was given a url that, in the documentation says the following:

> The response is a binary encoded octet stream of the raw 52 byte
>   archive records.

I created this code to test it out:

```
public static void GetHistory(string url)
{
  var response = WebRequestClasses.GetResponse(url);
  var nres = DeserializeObject(response);
  Console.WriteLine(nres);
}

public static object DeserializeObject(string str)
{
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);

  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  {
    return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
  }
}
```

It is returning the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.

I am getting a response as you can see from the print screen:

[image]

I've tried searching on octet parsing but I'm not getting anything. I'm not very familiar with encoding but I would assume it's a problem with the Base=64 vs octet stream?

Comment: Yes, it's not a base64 string. I'm guessing you're supposed to know what "archive record" means from some kind of context (e.g. the site you're getting the data from or the type of record you're requesting). Maybe by "archive record" it means it's a .zip file? At any rate, keep reading the documentation for clues.

Comment: @itsme86 Thank you for the reply. I didn't see anything in the rather short documentation so I contacted the company who sent it to me. Maybe they can shed some light on it.